# How to seed boolean True or False instead of 0 and 1 in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to seed my table boolean column with true or false instead of 0 or 1. I've tried a couple of tricks but all not working. Any help?

This is my seeder codes

```
public function definition()
    {
        return [
            'first_name' => fake()->firstName(),
            'last_name' => fake()->lastName(),
            'isPresent' => fake()->boolean(), 
        ];
    }
```

This is the migration code

```
Schema::create('students', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('first_name');
            $table->string('last_name');
            $table->boolean('isPresent')->default(false);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Comment: in the db, `true` or `false` is `1` or `0`, but in your models u can cast them to boolean `protected $casts = [ 'isPresent' => 'boolean', ];` https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting

Comment: also, u should use the same conventions for variables. in this case, i think u should follow `snake_case` for database fields. `isPresent` -> `is_present`